# sourcing harrassing texts

Tags: phone, incident-response, identity

I live in the US.  Someone is texting harrassing messages to me.  I have done a reverse lookup which dead-ends in a landline number.  The number I have has been confirmed by my wireless Carrier.  It appears that a scrambling application is being used to send the messages.  The police do not yet seem interested. How can I get to the source of the texts?

Comment: what is your country of origin (this will help people)

Comment: Your phone company is the only one who can trace the source. If they cannot, we cannot.

Answer (score 3):

If the harassment is bad enough to fulfill the definition of a crime in your jurisdiction, report it to the police. The public prosecutor can write a subpoena to the telephone provider which forces them to reveal the name and address of the person who is responsible for the text messages. This allows the prosecutor to press charges.

When the prosecution is unwilling to press charges, consult a local attorney and ask them what options you have in the legal system you are in.